# Data structure for objects with O(1) lookup?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I'm visiting nodes in a graph data structure. As I visit each node, I would add it to a "visited" list. It would be desirable to have an O(1) lookup to verify that I don't visit the same node more than once.

Of course, if each node has an associated value, I could use a regular JavaScript object (hash table) to store my "visited" list, but suppose I want to be agnostic to whether the node can evaluate to a string or not. Is there a JavaScript data structure that would support O(1) lookups for objects? How could I implement one?

Comment: Then use ES2015 [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (or [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) whichever suits better)

Comment: you can push to an array and use array.indexOf to see if a node ref is in the list, but that's probably slow. you could also set an invisible prop on the node itself, which is fast, but might break things depending on setup.

Comment: @zerkms I just checked my company-mandated browser against the compatibility list [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and cried a little bit :'(

Comment: @Blackhawk http://babeljs.io

Comment: @zerkms interesting... I'm going to take a look and see if I can figure out how they've implemented the functionality...

Comment: @Blackhawk or you can just take it and simply write using the modern standards :-)

Comment: @zerkms alas, I was a CS major... I MUST KNOW HOW THEY DO IT! :D

Comment: @zerkms can you make those two options an answer? I think that makes the most sense in writing future-proof code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) both added in ES2015.

And you don't need to wait for the browser support, since transpilers like [babel](http://babeljs.io/) have standard-compliant polyfills.

Comment: What about Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map ?

Answer (score 0):

To do O(1) lookups, you need to use a hash set.  There is no hash set in native javascript, but there is a hash map (plain object).  You can emulate a hash set by checking if the object contains the key.  Your value needs to implement the `toString` method.

```
var Set = function () {}
Set.prototype.contains = function (v) {
  return (v.toString() in this);
}
Set.prototype.add = function (v) {
  this[v.toString()] = true;
}
Set.prototype.remove = function (v) {
  delete this[v.toString()];
}
```

Comment: This breaks the condition that the set be agnostic to the value of each node. Suppose I'm providing this graph structure to be used as part of an API. If someone stores a few MB of text in each node (I know, not likely, but humor me), relying on that as a hash key would be terribly inefficient. I'd rather cut out the middle-man and use some inherent property of the object. Each JavaScript engine is aware of object equivalence `obj1 === obj2`, so I assume the functionality could be implemented even if it isn't exposed today.

Comment: You can use whatever hashing method you want.  The bottom line is that the hashing method has to return a string.  You could even just cast an integer as a string.

Comment: Also javascript engines are not aware of equivalence.  `===` actually returns if the two compared objects are the same object.  Proof: try `({a:1}) === ({a:1})` in your console.  If you want equivalence, assign each element a unique ID and return that as a string from your hashing method (which I chose to call `toString`)

Comment: If I was doing this in a different language, I would use the address of the object as my key. However I understand that in JavaScript and quite a few other languages with GC, the address of an object can change, so even if it was exposed it would be a bad idea. In Java, I believe the VM provides an "id" that is unique to a particular instance, which could be used for hashing. What bothers me and what prompted my question is that I KNOW the JavaScript engine has to keep track of which objects are which already - is it exposed somehow?

Comment: Yes, the kind of equivalence I'm looking for is instance equivalence, not duplicate values.

Comment: Suppose my nodes only have position, X and Y. Suppose that two of them happen to be at exactly the same position. If I visited these nodes, I would WANT for them not to be considered the same - I need to visit both of them. So yes, two node variables should only be equivalent if they reference the exact same node object.

Comment: If I were you, I would create a factory function that assigns a fresh id to each vertex it creates and returns

Comment: Yeah, so far I'm between going the id route and waiting for browser compliance with the new stuff that @zerkms mentioned. Thanks for your help and attention, by the way, much appreciated!